# jasmine leaves dashes without sign of why

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm having a problem with jasmine leaving tests unexecuted.  Well, they don't appear in the list of text descriptions of the tests, there are just unhelpful images of dashes that signify a test should run.  I'm running the entire test suite and have 12 / 2000-some tests not running for no apparent reason.

Is there a way to associate the actual name of the test with the icon?  I would like to know where they are coming from and there isn't any indication of it currently

Comment: Can you post any code that you think might be related to this issue?

Comment: well not really, I haven't changed much.  I can make the tests immediately before the dashes fail, but in the text list, the tests that come immediately after the failing tests do not seem to correlate to the dashes.  Meaning if I remove the tests that come after the failing tests(which should be the dashes), the dashes remain so the list of icons are not correlated to the list of descriptions.. oi

Comment: so does anyone know how to edit the icons so that I can see what line they came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! FOUND IT!

well, i started by isolating the test, and I quickly realized I was setting the test suites `this.id = 123`, which was breaking lots of stuff.  So if you have to keep track of an id for a test, make sure you namespace it better.